# how to use a BlazorWebView as component in Maui App

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I am building an app  and the app including menu etc.. is all in xaml,however I would like to use a BlazorWebView in one of the pages.

The app was not created using ".Net Maui Blazor app" but using ".NET MAUI App"

- Is there a template somewhere for this scenario?
- What do I need to add to have a blazorWebView in one of the pages?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BlazorWebView`'s name space is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui`.

So first of all is installing this nuget package in your project. And you can use different versions of it according your project.(I used the version 6.0.540 and my project is .net 6.0).

And then you need to change the project's Sdk from `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` by the first line code in the project.csproj file. This will fix the errors appear after you adding this nuget package into your project.

After this, I can delare a `BlazorWebView` in the maui project's content page. Both in the xaml and the code behind.

Finally, it seem using the maui control in the maui blazor project is easier than using the blazor control in the maui project. You can also try to move your code into a maui blazor app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - let me try - the other way round yes is much easier bcse its all hooked up - but is there an example somewhere that uses shell rather than the blazor menu-toolbar etc..?

Comment: Waiting for your reply and there is no a such example you want. I never try to use both blazor and maui shell together.  @developer9969

Comment: what about if you have a maui app and just 4-5 pages that uses webview - I think it would be a better experience to use a blazor component than the usual webView.WHat do you think?

Comment: Maybe you are right. And did the answer help you use the balzor webview in the maui? @developer9969

Comment: Thanks for your help - still lots of doubts about the area -learning curve